# Entity Framework - Discriminator column being created with TPT

Tags: c#, entity-framework, table-per-type

So I am trying to implement Table-per-Type using Entity Framework code first, however a discriminator column is still being created in the AspNetUsers table (ApplicationUser class) even though I have told it otherwise.

DbContext

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SchoolContext, School.Migrations.Configuration>());

        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().ToTable("Teachers");
    }  

    public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

POCOs of classes in question, including ApplicationUser which uses ASP Identity:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Student: ApplicationUser
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects{ get; set; }
}

public class Teacher: ApplicationUser
{
    public virtual int Wage{ get; set; }
}
```

The resulting database schema seems to insert a 'Discriminator' column, though when I register a new account through the website, the column shows "undefined" for the row anyway.

Things I have tried:
Adding to the OnModelCreating for ApplicationUser being created with a ToTable("AspNetUsers") etc

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: did you try to completely remove the database, and then building it again using Migrations?

Comment: Your setup looks right for TPT. Perhaps Discriminator column is left over from previous build as EF uses TPH by default. eg if you built the app before putting in `modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students");`

Comment: Yes, I've deleted the database and all migrations, added another migration with TPT changes but the column is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. It turns out you have to have fluent API table mapping for all of the classes in the hierarchy. Because you do not have a mapping  for ApplicationUser and IdentityUser, EF is thinking that you are intending to use Type Per Concrete strategy. I recommend making ApplicationUser encapsulate IdentityUser if you don't want to define a table for IdentityUser as well as define a table mapping for ApplicationUser.

A quick test would be to add a mapping for ApplicationUser to AspNetUsers and remove inheritance from IdentityUser and see if that helps.

I hope that helps.

Thanks,
Abe Billah.